# Tail grep what tools are for it

Tags: grep, tail

I would like to run the following command:

```
tail -f /var/log/syslog | grep -ri 00:16:CB:1E:AF:CA
```

In Linux but it does not working. How would you interactively grep certain text from log files?

Comment: Duplicate question http://stackoverflow.com/q/7161821

Answer (score 3):

grep -r (recursive) makes no sense in your case, since you are just searching in a single file. Just use `tail -f /var/log/syslog | grep -i 00:16:CB:1E:AF:CA`.

Comment: If applied to a single file, `tail` and `tail -r` are equivalent. `-r` might be redundant, but omiting it won't help.

Comment: What? `tail -r`? I just corrected `grep -ri` which **IS** wrong.

Comment: Oh dear ... i did mean `grep` of course. Still: Why is `grep -ri` wrong?

Comment: Well, I don't know your setup but on my Debian Wheezy `tail -f file | grep -ri something` also starts searching in every file in the directory I'm in.

Comment: You are of course correct - sorry! Need more coffee.

Answer (score 1):

As per stackoverflow

```
tailf file | grep --line-buffered 00:16:CB:1E:AF:CA
```

should do the trick